# Better way to rename arguments to a functional form so that duplicate arguments are sequentially enumerated

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

I need to modify expressions that such as `f[w, w, a, y, x, a, x, a]` into `f[w1, w2, a1, y, x1, a2, x2, a3]`.

In short, I have expressions like `head[args__]`, and I want to modify `args` in such a way so as to have the arguments that appear multiple times in the argument list enumerate themselves sequentially and return the modified expression.

My code so far feels a bit clunky but it works on the test cases I considered relevant.

Here are some examples:

```
h[o,i,o,s,d] -> h[o1,i,o2,s,d]
h[o,i,s,o,d] -> h[o1,i,s,o2,d]
h[o,i,s,d,o] -> h[o1,i,s,d,o2]
h[i,o,s,o,d] -> h[i,o1,s,o2,d]
h[i,o,s,d,o] -> h[i,o1,s,d,o2]
h[i,s,o,d,o] -> h[i,s,o1,d,o2]
h[o,i,o,s,o,d] -> h[o1,i,o2,s,o3,d]
h[o,i,o,s,d,o] -> h[o1,i,o2,s,d,o3]
h[o,i,s,o,d,o] -> h[o1,i,s,o2,d,o3]
h[i,o,s,o,d,o] -> h[i,o1,s,o2,d,o3]
h[o,i,o,s,o,d,o] -> h[o1,i,o2,s,o3,d,o4]
```

And here's how the previous result was obtained:

```
{h[o, i, o, s, d], h[o, i, s, o, d], h[o, i, s, d, o], h[i, o, s, o, d], h[i, o, s, d, o], 
 h[i, s, o, d, o], h[o, i, o, s, o, d], h[o, i, o, s, d, o], h[o, i, s, o, d, o], 
 h[i, o, s, o, d, o], h[o, i, o, s, o, d, o]} /. h[args__] :> h @@ enumArgs[args]
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

An extension I'm considering is

```
SetAttributes[modArgs, HoldAll]

modArgs[h_[args__]] := h @@ enumArgs[args]
```

without having to rely on `ReplaceAll`, but I was wondering if `enumArgs` — or something similar — can be coded otherwise.

Things I think could use some improvement:

1. `enumArg` makes use of `ToString` and `Symbol`. In the context, I'm using `enumArgs` there doesn't seem to be any **obvious** way for things to go wrong, since I'm making sure I'm using atomic arguments for the heads and arguments of heads. But that may not *always* be the case.
2. `enumArg` and `enumArgs` to some extent feel more *procedural* than I'd be comfortable with.
3. `enumArgs` plows through the argument list and does what it's supposed to do. I think it should be more '*discrete*'.
4. Also in `enumArgs`, using the *magic* in `Part` to perform in-place assignments is a fast way to do what you need to do, but feels a bit *sloppy*.

Would you agree with some/any of the points I raise above? Do you think it could have been done better?

If you disagree or think otherwise, please let me know.

---

### Code

Process single argument:

```
(* process a single argument *)
enumArg[argument_, count_, index_] := Module[{res, id = index},

  If[
   count > 1,
   
   (* more than one instances *)
   res = Symbol@StringJoin[ToString[argument], ToString[count - index + 1]];
   id = index - 1,
   
   (* single instance *)
   res = argument
  ];
  
  {res, id}
  
]
```

Process function arguments:

```
(* process arguments *)
enumArgs[args__] := Module[{tally, count, pos, junk, bag = {}, res, id, argument, index},

  (* count individual instances of arguments *)
  tally = Tally[{args}];

  count = tally[[All, -1]];

  (
     {{pos, junk}} = Position[tally, #];
 
     {argument, index} = tally[[pos]];
 
     {res, id} = enumArg[argument, count[[pos]], index];
 
     bag = Flatten[{bag, res}];
 
     tally[[pos, -1]] = id;
 
     ) & /@ {args};

  bag
]
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
modArgs[res : h_[args__]] := Module[{pos, sym, tl},
   tl = Tally[{args}];
   pos = Table[Position[{args}, id, 1], {id, tl[[All, 1]]}];
   sym = Function[{n, c}, If[c > 1, 
                             Array[Symbol[ToString[n] <> IntegerString[#1]] &, c],
                             {n}]] @@@ tl;
   ReplacePart[res, Flatten[MapThread[Thread@*Rule, {pos, sym}, 1]]]]
```

For example,

```
modArgs[f[w, w, a, y, x, a, x, a]]
   f[w1, w2, a1, y, x1, a2, x2, a3]

modArgs[h[o, i, o, s, o, d, o]]
   h[o1, i, o2, s, o3, d, o4]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[indexArgs]

indexArgs = Module[{counts = Counts[List @@ #], assoc}, 
    assoc = 1 & /@ counts;
    Replace[ #,  x_Symbol /; counts[x] > 1 :> 
      Symbol[SymbolName[x] <> ToString[assoc[x]++]], All, Heads -> False]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Grid[{#, indexArgs @ #} & /@ {h[o, i, o, s, d], h[o, i, s, o, d], 
    h[o, i, s, d, o], h[i, o, s, o, d], h[i, o, s, d, o], 
    h[i, s, o, d, o], h[o, i, o, s, o, d], h[o, i, o, s, d, o], 
    h[o, i, s, o, d, o], h[i, o, s, o, d, o], h[o, i, o, s, o, d, o], 
    h[w, w, a, y, x, a, x, a]} // Prepend[#, {"expr", "indexArgs @ expr"}] &,
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]